# Scala "match" help

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am studying some scala code and found this method which baffles me. In the match statement, what is the `sublist@` construct? what kind of value does it contains? when I printed it its no diff than `tail`, but if I replace it with tail, the function returns diff result. Can somebody explain what it is and point me to a right resource to understand it? (I know I can search in google, but don't know what to look for..)

```
def flatMapSublists[A, B](ls: List[A])(f: (List[A]) => List[B]): List[B] =
    ls match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case sublist@(_ :: tail) => f(sublist) ::: flatMapSublists(tail)(f)
    }
```

Comment: `@` is usually used in annotations, but I see nothing of the like here...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would call it the "eat your cake and have it too operator". At any level in pattern matching, you can give a part a name (before the @) and deconstruct it further (after the @). For instance imagine you want to match against a List with 3 elements, you need the second element, but you want to log the whole list:

```
something match {
  case list@List(_,elem,_) => log("matching:" + list); elem    
  case _ => error("not found")
}
```

Without this feature, you had to write something like

```
something match {
  case List(a,elem,b) => log("matching:" + List(a,elem,b)); elem    
  case _ => error("not found")
}
```

As you can see, we need to name the first and third element, just because we need them to get a list with the same structure on the right side, which is boilerplate. It is much easier and clearer if you can give the whole thing a name (`list`), and parts deeper in the structure as well (`elem`), when you need both on the right side.

Answer (score 8):

In this instance, sublist becomes a named variable for the entire list `(_ :: tail)`.  tail is the, well, tail of the list.  I'm not sure if there is a proper name for '@' here.

I don't really see the purpose of sublist here, since you can just reference `ls` directly.

Disclaimer:  I'm new to scala.  I hope I got this right.

Comment: It's the same in Haskell (and propably ML), too.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Both the answers helped me understand it.

Comment: It’s called a ‘pattern binder’ in the language reference.

Comment: +1 for the point that I don't need to use it here and I can use `ls` instead.